# How to iterate over an abstract collection in C++?

Tags: c++, collections, interface, iterator, polymorphism

I have an interface. The interface contains a method that somehow must let a user iterate through a collection. Usually, I use a vector as the collection, so I could write the code like this:

```
class Object;

template<typename T>
using VectorIterators = std::pair<typename std::vector<T>::iterator, typename std::vector<T>::iterator>;

class Interface {
public:
    virtual VectorIterators<Object> ListObjects() = 0;
};
```

(ListObjects returns a pair of begin and end iterators of the vector)
But in this case, I make classes that implement this interface use vector for storing objects, but sometimes it may be inefficient so I would want to use a `list` for example, since `vector` would slow my program down. I also don't want to return the collection, just want to let the user iterate through it.

So is there a way in C++ to iterate through an abstract collection that may store data in memory in any way?
Do you have any ideas on how to solve it?
Hope for your help!

Comment: That's exactly what the C++'s own algorithms do, and why many of them require a beginning iterator and an ending iterator.  Template meta-programming can accommodate what you need.

Comment: `std::list` is slower than `std::vector` for almost everything. Despite using C++ for ~20 years now, I've never yet encountered a real world scenario where a `std::list` was faster. (Though I do know of a few hypothetical scenarios, I've simply never encountered them)

Comment: [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is already doing this. Check how it's implemented to give yourself and idea to what you can do.

Comment: OP: Do you _need_ dynamic dispatch instead of static dispatch?

Comment: Abstract iterators are SLOW. If you need dynamic dispatch, the best you're going to do is to pass a dynamic _function_ to the container, and have the container do the iterating itself.

Comment: @MooingDuck, a callback is a good idea, I think I will use it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the template argument for the container instead of the containers content:

```
template<typename T>
using Iterators = std::pair<typename T::iterator, typename T::iterator>;
```

Of course you then need to specify the container when using `Iterators`:

```
class Interface {
public:
    virtual Iterators<std::vector<Object>> ListObjects() = 0;
};
```

---

You can of course make `Interface` a template as well, if the container type isn't known until the concrete classes which implements the interface. But that makes it harder to use polymorphism with pointers to the abstract `Interface`.

Comment: In this case, the derivatives of this interface still have to use a vector for storing objects.